# How to limit by week with multiple weeks?

Tags: sql, hive, limit

In my query below, I am trying to bring back the top 750 order IDs (by CTR) for each week.

Not the top 750 out of all weeks.  I can't figure out how to do that.

```
select "topctrbyQ32015", weekofyear(day),order_id, (sum(clicks)/sum(impressions)) as ctr
from RDZ_TABLE rdz
where day >= '2015-07-06'
and day <= '2015-09-27'
group by "topctrbyQ32015", weekofyear(day),order_id
order by ctr desc
limit 750;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use windowing functions (available in Hive 0.11 and later):

```
select
    woy,
    order_id,
    ctr,
    rank() OVER (partition by woy order by ctr desc) as ctr_rank
from
    ( select 
        weekofyear(day) as woy,
        order_id, 
        (sum(clicks)/sum(impressions)) as ctr
    from 
        RDZ_TABLE rdz
    where 
        day >= '2015-07-06'
        and day <= '2015-09-27'
    group by 
        weekofyear(day),order_id
    ) z
where
    rank() OVER (partition by woy order by ctr desc) <= 750
```

For more details see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-PARTITIONBYwithonepartitioningcolumn,noORDERBYorwindowspecification